# Adding anagrams to a dictionary from a .txt file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a text file which is a long list of words with no spaces e.g"neuropsychologicalneuropsychologistneuropsychologyneuropsychopathic" etc
I am trying to build a program that will take an inputted word and check the .txt file for any anagrams of the word and then add them to a dictionary.

The code I have come up with so far that prints 1 dictionary with 1 permutation contained in words.txt is;

```
anagram_dict  = {}

def anagram(word):

    b = open('words.txt', 'r').readlines()
    text = ''.join(line.strip() for line in b)

    #print(len(text))

    for i in range(len(text)-len(word)):
        prop = text[i:i+len(word)]
        if all(char in word for char in prop): #and all(prop.count(char) == prop.count(word) for char in prop):
            anagram_dict[''.join(sorted(word))] = [prop]

    print(anagram_dict)

anagram("demand")
```

The issue is that the permutation it prints isn't an anagram (I input "demand" expecting "madden"to come out but it prints "amamad" which is in the file but not an anagram) How can I make it so that it only prints the dictionary if the permutation is a true anagram (same letters just rearranged)?

I think the problem is possibly with the "if all(char in word for char in prop): # and all(prop.count(char) == prop.count(word) for char in prop):"

Especially the part that's commented out as when that runs it just prints an empty string.

Apologies for this being so long I just wanted to make sure I explained myself. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`all(char in word for char in prop)` simply checks if all the letters of `word` are in `prop`.
All the letters of demand are `"present"` in `"madden"`, so it would show up in the results.

There is problem with `all(prop.count(char) == prop.count(word) for char in prop)` (probably a typo).

It should be `all(prop.count(char) == word.count(char) for char in prop)`

---

There is also a better alternative, check if sorted versions of `prop` and `word` are same.

```
sword = ''.join(sorted(word))
anagram_dict[sword] = []
for i in range(len(text)-len(word)):
    prop = text[i:i+len(word)]
    if sword == ''.join(sorted(prop)):
        anagram_dict[sword].append(prop)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it now prints all the permutations in one dictionary but now I'm trying to make it so that it only adds permutations that are contained within words.txt into said dictionary. I thought it may simply be "and if check in text/b" but that just prints the dictionary with an empty value.

Comment: Append anagrams in a separate list. Then after the loop is over, check if that list is empty or not. If it isn't, you can add that list to your dictionary.